# Moving only the contents of a map and not the map itself on linux

Tags: linux, command-line, cp

Using the `cp` command, one can move files and folders on linux.

I want to make a new user and move the contents of the skeleton map to their home directory.

I use this command:

```
cp -r /etc/skel/ /home/testuser/
```

However, this only creates a `skel` folder in testuser. The idea is that the contents of the `/etc/skel` folder be copied to `/home/testuser`, and not that a map be made in `/home/testuser` with those contents.

I've checked the man page: [Link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp), but nothing on there really seemed like the solution to me.

Is there a way to do this, or do files really need to be moved manually, 1 by 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating new users on the system manually from the command-line using the `useradd` command, the `-m` switch can be used to automatically create a home directory as well as copy the contents of the skeleton directory into it.

In your case, however, the following will be sufficient:

```
cp -R /etc/skel/* /home/testuser/
```

Comment: Sadly, this did not copy the contents. Instead, there is now an empty folder `/home/testuser/testuser`

Comment: Even worse, every folder I now create with useradd has the empty "testuser" folder in it. Even after a restart, it still happens.

Comment: Even after deleting the user and cleaning the passwd and shadow file and restarting, it is *still* happening.

Comment: @WebDevHobo: It sounds like you may have copied testuser into skel by reversing the arguments to `cp` or somehow overwritten the contents of skel or created a symlink in it. What does `ls -la /etc/skel` give you?

Comment: Yes, the empty folder was indeed now located in skel for some reason. I don't remember doing it...

Comment: Now I'm getting the message that I "can't apply stat on '/etc/skel/*': File or folder does not exist." Working on Debian 5 btw.